# Filter anonymous email on Gmail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, filter, gmail

It's remarkably easy to send emails anonymously, hiding one's own address and sometimes even making it look as if the email originates from another person's address.

On Gmail, you can check the origin of the email by clicking `Other` then see the origin of the message. But it's quite annoying to do these steps each time you receive an email.

Is there any already existing script or any solution that filter these messages?

Comment: StackOverflow is for help writing your own functions. You may be able to find existing scripts on SuperUser.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: This does sound like a Gmail app question, rather than a GAS question.  The Gmail filter help may be the best place to look: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en.